# Output in unknown state even though specified in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am having some troubles with creating an edge detector in verilog. So far I've come up with this:

```
module edge_detector (  
        input     ce,               // Clock enable.
        input     data,             // Data signal for edge detection.
        output reg detected,        // Output signal that goes high when edge is detected.
        input     reset,            // Active high reset.
        input     clk,              // Clock.
        input     [1:0] edge_sel,   // Edge selection. Look in description for details.
        output     sim_prev_data    // Simulation variable. Previous data state.
    );

    reg prev_data = 'bx;    // Previous data signal level state.

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            detected <= 0;
            prev_data <= 'bx;
        end else if (ce) begin
            // Upon initialization or after reset prev_data state is unknown.
            // So after first clock tick prev_data is set, but detected output
            // should stay low.
            if (prev_data == 'bx) begin
                prev_data <= data;
                detected <= 0;
            end else begin
                case (edge_sel)
                    'b00: detected = (prev_data == 0 && data == 1);     // Rising edge.
                    'b01: detected = (prev_data == 1 && data == 0);     // Falling edge.                    
                    'b10: detected = ((prev_data == 0 && data == 1) ||  // Any edge.
                                      (prev_data == 1 && data == 0));       
                    'b11: detected = ((prev_data == 0 && data == 0) ||  // No edge change.
                                      (prev_data == 1 && data == 1));           
                endcase

                prev_data = data;
            end
        end
    end

    assign sim_prev_data = prev_data;
endmodule
```

[image: waves]

Picture represents simulation waveform generated by iverilog and gtkwave. As can be seen when `reset=1` also `detected=0` and `prev_data=x`. When reset goes low and on first rising edge of a clock tick, marked by red line, `detected` has a value of `x`. Even though I have explicitly defined `detected<=0;` under `...if (prev_data == 'bx) begin...`,

Why doesnt `detected` have a value of 0 after reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a comment, but will expand it into an answer.

The logical equality operator is just that, logical. Anything that is not a 1 or a 0 results in an unknown (x) output. The case equality operator (`prev_data==='bx`) will require matching of `x` as well as `0` and `1`. However the use of `x` in physical synthesis makes no sense - a bit in hardware will be either `1` or `0`.

What your comment describes `Upon initialization or after reset prev_data state is unknown.` doesn't make sense. After reset, you should specifically initialise the value to something. In physical hardware, how can `x` be distinguished? A register can't be `x`, only `1` or `0`. So you should ensure that after reset it is set to a known value.

If you wish to achieve what your comment in the code implies, you can simply create a delayed reset signal and use that as a signal that reset has just been deasserted. For example, the following would achieve what you describe:

```
reg prev_data = 'b0;    // Previous data signal level state.

reg exit_reset;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset || ce) begin
        exit_reset <= reset; // Exit reset is the reset signal delayed by one cycle, or until the clock is enabled.
    end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        detected <= 0;
        prev_data <= 'b0; //Initialise to a known value
    end else if (ce) begin
        // Upon initialization or after reset prev_data state is incorrect.
        if (exit_reset) begin
            //If we just exited reset, then initialise prev_data but keep detected low.
            prev_data <= data;
            detected <= 0;
        end else begin
            ....
            prev_data = data;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Doesnt x in verilog also means "dont care". By setting some variable to x, I am essentialy saying: "I dont care what value this will be, because I will initialize it to appropriate value when I will need it." Wouldnt this enable the synthesis tool to further optimize the solution? P.S I've changed the original code to include another reg, that is 0 upon initialiazation and reset, and goes to 1 after one clock tick. So upon initialiozation and reset prev_data=x but after one clock tick it gets the right value: prev_data=data. The simulation works. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also  detected output only changes after two clock ticks, after first prev_data gets some value (not x) and after second detected output changes to appropriate value.

Comment: @Golaž that's a common misconception. ```x``` doesn't mean "don't care", in means "unknown". There is quite a big difference. If you tell the synthesis tool to initialise something to ```x``` it will likely either give you an error, or initialise it to ```0```. The only time ```x``` should really be used is in ```casex``` statements to indicate to the synthesis tool that a bit can be ignored when matching it to a case value.

Comment: Is there a "dont care" value in verilog? How can I tell the synthesis tool that I dont care what the value is, and just let it choose some value that would produce the most optimized solution?

Comment: @Golaž You don't. You tell it zero (or one), and have optimisation enabled. Let the synthesis tool do its work. It will do things like NOT-gate push back (bubble pushing) as it sees fit. In a case like yours where it makes absolutely no difference whether the gate is initialised to 1 or to 0, just pick one of them (0 is the easiest).

Comment: Also, you said I should assign some value to `prev_data` in reset. Is this really necessary in this case or can I just leave it out? I mean, I only use `prev_data` value when it is already correctly assigned, this is after `exit_reset` in your case.

Comment: @Golaž yes, you can simply not put an initialization line. If you do this all that will happen is the synthesizer will choose the default initialization value which is usually 0. This will show up as unknown in a simulation.

Comment: Is there any advantage of  making another always block like you did for `exit_reset` or could one just put `exit_reset<=1;` inside the same always block under reset and then under `if (exit_reset) begin` set `reset<=0;`. This was the first thing that came to my mind from experience with software programming. What is the difference between those solutions?

Comment: @Golaž Behavior wise there is no difference. However I find it makes things easier to follow if you break them up - ```exit_reset``` is really its own independent signal, so why put it in an always block with lots of other stuff. It comes down to a difference in paradigm between HDL and procedural languages. In procedural you are trying to minimize the number of lines to be executed, whereas in HDL the number of lines is meaningless to the final design size/speed - so use as many as you like, make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`detected` is a function of signal `prev_data` which is undefined at the clock instance that you indicate.

Upon reset, you have to set `prev_data` to something. That's what the reset is for.

I don't think that `prev_data == 'bx` has any practical meaning at all... `'bx` is not a value, so it cannot be compared to a value. This cannot be synthesized. If you are trying to do something behavioral only, change the type of your variable and assign something different. Say you make it an integer, then use -1 for "undefined", 0 for 0 and 1 for 1.

Comment: Ahh I see. For some reason I though that synthesis tool can differ between 0,1 and X and implement a solution which would wait one clock tick. Exactly, I though synthesis tool will be able to "know" that by `prev_data=='bx` I really wanted to check if prev_data was already set or not.

Comment: @Golaž the logical equality operator is just that, logical. Anything that is not a 1 or a 0 results in an unknown (x) output. The case equality operator (```prev_data==='bx```) will require matching of ```x``` as well as ```0``` and ```1```. However the use of ```x``` in physical synthesis makes no sense - a bit in hardware will be either ```1``` or ```0```.